# React: show object as working JS format?

Tags: javascript, json, object, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am working on a project in which I get into given situation:

```
myjson:
{
    completeName: "my name is {this.state.myName+ " "+this.state.surname}"
}
```

**component.js**

```
var Component = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function() {
        return({
            myName: "AKHA",
            surname: "HUND"
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{myData.completeName}</div>
        )
    }
})
```

but I am getting output as:

```
my name is {this.state.myName+ " "+this.state.surname}
```

instead of:

```
my name is AKHA HUND***
```

please help me.

Note: using ES5.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you store in your `.json` is a string, not an expression, it is not evaluated in any way, you have to modify the template in your JS code.

Using ES5 you could do something like this:

**.json**

```
{
  completeName: "my name is %myName %surname"
}
```

**component.js**

```
var Component= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return({
            myName: "AKHA",
            surname: "HUND"
        })
    },
    render: function(){
        const result = myData.completeName
            .replace("%myName", this.state.myName)
            .replace("%surname", this.state.surname);

        return (
            <div>{ result }</div>
        )
    }
})
```